# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol in cocos2d-x lua support

Tags: c++, lua, cocos2d-x

I have created a cpp cocos2d-x project, and manually add lua support(import the liblua project in my solution). I want to run lua code in my cocos2d-x project. But I met these errors. I cannot use any functions in "CCLuaEngine.h". When I try to write some lua api code , there still unresolved external symbol errors.

my cocos2d-x version is 2.1.5 , and I use visual studio 2012 under Windows 7
following picture is my project.
[image: project structure]

```
1>liblua.lib(tolua_to.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushnumber
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaEngine.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushnumber referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall cocos2d::CCLuaEngine::executeLayerTouchesEvent(class cocos2d::CCLayer *,int,class cocos2d::CCSet *)" (?executeLayerTouchesEvent@CCLuaEngine@cocos2d@@UAEHPAVCCLayer@2@HPAVCCSet@2@@Z)
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaStack.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushnumber
1>liblua.lib(tolua_is.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushnumber
1>liblua.lib(tolua_push.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushnumber
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaEngine.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushinteger referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall cocos2d::CCLuaEngine::executeLayerTouchesEvent(class cocos2d::CCLayer *,int,class cocos2d::CCSet *)" (?executeLayerTouchesEvent@CCLuaEngine@cocos2d@@UAEHPAVCCLayer@2@HPAVCCSet@2@@Z)
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaStack.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushinteger
1>liblua.lib(tolua_fix.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushinteger
1>liblua.lib(tolua_event.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_createtable
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaEngine.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_createtable referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall cocos2d::CCLuaEngine::executeLayerTouchesEvent(class cocos2d::CCLayer *,int,class cocos2d::CCSet *)" (?executeLayerTouchesEvent@CCLuaEngine@cocos2d@@UAEHPAVCCLayer@2@HPAVCCSet@2@@Z)
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaStack.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_createtable
1>liblua.lib(tolua_fix.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_createtable
1>liblua.lib(tolua_map.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_createtable
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaEngine.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_rawseti referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall cocos2d::CCLuaEngine::executeLayerTouchesEvent(class cocos2d::CCLayer *,int,class cocos2d::CCSet *)" (?executeLayerTouchesEvent@CCLuaEngine@cocos2d@@UAEHPAVCCLayer@2@HPAVCCSet@2@@Z)
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaStack.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_rawseti
1>liblua.lib(tolua_push.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_gettop
1>liblua.lib(tolua_map.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_gettop
1>liblua.lib(tolua_to.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_gettop
1>liblua.lib(tolua_event.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_gettop
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaStack.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_gettop referenced in function "int __cdecl `anonymous namespace'::lua_print(struct lua_State *)" (?lua_print@?A0x5bb22735@@YAHPAUlua_State@@@Z)
1>liblua.lib(tolua_fix.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_gettop
1>liblua.lib(LuaCocos2d.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_gettop
1>liblua.lib(tolua_is.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_gettop
1>liblua.lib(tolua_map.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_settop
1>liblua.lib(tolua_to.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_settop
1>liblua.lib(tolua_event.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_settop
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaStack.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_settop referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall cocos2d::CCLuaStack::addLuaLoader(int (__cdecl*)(struct lua_State *))" (?addLuaLoader@CCLuaStack@cocos2d@@UAEXP6AHPAUlua_State@@@Z@Z)
1>liblua.lib(tolua_fix.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_settop
1>liblua.lib(tolua_is.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_settop
1>liblua.lib(tolua_push.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_settop
1>liblua.lib(tolua_event.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_insert
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaStack.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_insert referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall cocos2d::CCLuaStack::executeFunction(int)" (?executeFunction@CCLuaStack@cocos2d@@UAEHH@Z)
1>liblua.lib(tolua_is.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_insert
1>liblua.lib(tolua_push.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_insert
1>liblua.lib(tolua_map.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_insert
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaStack.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_isnumber referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall cocos2d::CCLuaStack::executeFunction(int)" (?executeFunction@CCLuaStack@cocos2d@@UAEHH@Z)
1>liblua.lib(tolua_is.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_isnumber
1>liblua.lib(tolua_event.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_isnumber
1>liblua.lib(tolua_map.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_type
1>liblua.lib(tolua_to.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_type
1>liblua.lib(tolua_event.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_type
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaStack.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_type referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall cocos2d::CCLuaStack::executeFunction(int)" (?executeFunction@CCLuaStack@cocos2d@@UAEHH@Z)
1>liblua.lib(tolua_fix.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_type
1>liblua.lib(tolua_is.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_type
1>liblua.lib(tolua_push.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_type
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaStack.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_typename referenced in function "int __cdecl `anonymous namespace'::lua_print(struct lua_State *)" (?lua_print@?A0x5bb22735@@YAHPAUlua_State@@@Z)
1>liblua.lib(tolua_fix.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_typename
1>liblua.lib(tolua_is.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_typename
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaStack.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_tointeger referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall cocos2d::CCLuaStack::executeFunction(int)" (?executeFunction@CCLuaStack@cocos2d@@UAEHH@Z)
1>liblua.lib(tolua_to.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_toboolean
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaStack.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_toboolean referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall cocos2d::CCLuaStack::executeFunction(int)" (?executeFunction@CCLuaStack@cocos2d@@UAEHH@Z)
1>liblua.lib(tolua_fix.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_toboolean
1>liblua.lib(tolua_is.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_toboolean
1>liblua.lib(tolua_push.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_toboolean
1>liblua.lib(tolua_to.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_tolstring
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaStack.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_tolstring referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall cocos2d::CCLuaStack::addSearchPath(char const *)" (?addSearchPath@CCLuaStack@cocos2d@@UAEXPBD@Z)
1>liblua.lib(tolua_fix.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_tolstring
1>liblua.lib(Cocos2dxLuaLoader.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_tolstring
1>liblua.lib(tolua_is.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_tolstring
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaStack.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_objlen referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall cocos2d::CCLuaStack::addLuaLoader(int (__cdecl*)(struct lua_State *))" (?addLuaLoader@CCLuaStack@cocos2d@@UAEXP6AHPAUlua_State@@@Z@Z)
1>liblua.lib(tolua_event.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushnil
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaStack.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushnil referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall cocos2d::CCLuaStack::pushNil(void)" (?pushNil@CCLuaStack@cocos2d@@UAEXXZ)
1>liblua.lib(tolua_fix.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushnil
1>liblua.lib(tolua_push.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushnil
1>liblua.lib(tolua_map.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushnil
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaStack.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushlstring referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall cocos2d::CCLuaStack::pushString(char const *,int)" (?pushString@CCLuaStack@cocos2d@@UAEXPBDH@Z)
1>liblua.lib(tolua_is.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushlstring
1>liblua.lib(tolua_map.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushlstring
1>liblua.lib(tolua_event.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushlstring
1>liblua.lib(tolua_push.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushstring
1>liblua.lib(tolua_map.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushstring
1>liblua.lib(tolua_event.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushstring
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaStack.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushstring referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall cocos2d::CCLuaStack::pushCCLuaValueDict(class std::map<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class cocos2d::CCLuaValue,struct std::less<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const ,class cocos2d::CCLuaValue> > > const &)" (?pushCCLuaValueDict@CCLuaStack@cocos2d@@UAEXABV?$map@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@VCCLuaValue@cocos2d@@U?$less@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@VCCLuaValue@cocos2d@@@std@@@2@@std@@@Z)
1>liblua.lib(tolua_fix.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushstring
1>liblua.lib(LuaCocos2d.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushstring
1>liblua.lib(tolua_is.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushstring
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaStack.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushfstring referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall cocos2d::CCLuaStack::addSearchPath(char const *)" (?addSearchPath@CCLuaStack@cocos2d@@UAEXPBD@Z)
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaStack.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushcclosure referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall cocos2d::CCLuaStack::addLuaLoader(int (__cdecl*)(struct lua_State *))" (?addLuaLoader@CCLuaStack@cocos2d@@UAEXP6AHPAUlua_State@@@Z@Z)
1>liblua.lib(tolua_map.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushcclosure
1>liblua.lib(tolua_event.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushcclosure
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaStack.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushboolean referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall cocos2d::CCLuaStack::pushBoolean(bool)" (?pushBoolean@CCLuaStack@cocos2d@@UAEX_N@Z)
1>liblua.lib(tolua_push.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushboolean
1>liblua.lib(tolua_map.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushboolean
1>liblua.lib(tolua_event.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushboolean
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaStack.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_getfield referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall cocos2d::CCLuaStack::addLuaLoader(int (__cdecl*)(struct lua_State *))" (?addLuaLoader@CCLuaStack@cocos2d@@UAEXP6AHPAUlua_State@@@Z@Z)
1>liblua.lib(tolua_fix.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_getfield
1>liblua.lib(tolua_push.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_getfield
1>liblua.lib(tolua_map.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_getfield
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaStack.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_rawgeti referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall cocos2d::CCLuaStack::addLuaLoader(int (__cdecl*)(struct lua_State *))" (?addLuaLoader@CCLuaStack@cocos2d@@UAEXP6AHPAUlua_State@@@Z@Z)
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaStack.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_setfield referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall cocos2d::CCLuaStack::addLuaLoader(int (__cdecl*)(struct lua_State *))" (?addLuaLoader@CCLuaStack@cocos2d@@UAEXP6AHPAUlua_State@@@Z@Z)
1>liblua.lib(tolua_event.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_rawset
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaStack.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_rawset referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall cocos2d::CCLuaStack::pushCCLuaValueDict(class std::map<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class cocos2d::CCLuaValue,struct std::less<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const ,class cocos2d::CCLuaValue> > > const &)" (?pushCCLuaValueDict@CCLuaStack@cocos2d@@UAEXABV?$map@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@VCCLuaValue@cocos2d@@U?$less@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@VCCLuaValue@cocos2d@@@std@@@2@@std@@@Z)
1>liblua.lib(tolua_fix.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_rawset
1>liblua.lib(tolua_push.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_rawset
1>liblua.lib(tolua_map.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_rawset
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaStack.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_pcall referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall cocos2d::CCLuaStack::executeFunction(int)" (?executeFunction@CCLuaStack@cocos2d@@UAEHH@Z)
1>liblua.lib(tolua_map.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pcall
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaStack.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_error referenced in function "public: virtual bool __thiscall cocos2d::CCLuaStack::handleAssert(char const *)" (?handleAssert@CCLuaStack@cocos2d@@UAE_NPBD@Z)
1>liblua.lib(tolua_map.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_error
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaStack.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _luaL_register referenced in function "protected: bool __thiscall cocos2d::CCLuaStack::init(void)" (?init@CCLuaStack@cocos2d@@IAE_NXZ)
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaStack.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _luaL_loadfile referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall cocos2d::CCLuaStack::executeScriptFile(char const *)" (?executeScriptFile@CCLuaStack@cocos2d@@UAEHPBD@Z)
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaStack.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _luaL_loadstring referenced in function "public: virtual int __thiscall cocos2d::CCLuaStack::executeString(char const *)" (?executeString@CCLuaStack@cocos2d@@UAEHPBD@Z)
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaStack.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _luaL_newstate referenced in function "protected: bool __thiscall cocos2d::CCLuaStack::init(void)" (?init@CCLuaStack@cocos2d@@IAE_NXZ)
1>liblua.lib(CCLuaStack.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _luaL_openlibs referenced in function "protected: bool __thiscall cocos2d::CCLuaStack::init(void)" (?init@CCLuaStack@cocos2d@@IAE_NXZ)
1>liblua.lib(tolua_event.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushvalue
1>liblua.lib(tolua_fix.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushvalue referenced in function _toluafix_ref_function
1>liblua.lib(tolua_is.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushvalue
1>liblua.lib(tolua_push.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushvalue
1>liblua.lib(tolua_map.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushvalue
1>liblua.lib(tolua_fix.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_remove referenced in function _toluafix_get_function_by_refid
1>liblua.lib(tolua_push.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_remove
1>liblua.lib(tolua_event.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_remove
1>liblua.lib(tolua_fix.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_tonumber referenced in function _toluafix_stack_dump
1>liblua.lib(tolua_to.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_tonumber
1>liblua.lib(tolua_event.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_touserdata
1>liblua.lib(tolua_fix.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_touserdata referenced in function _toluafix_remove_ccobject_by_refid
1>liblua.lib(LuaCocos2d.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_touserdata
1>liblua.lib(tolua_map.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_touserdata
1>liblua.lib(tolua_to.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_touserdata
1>liblua.lib(tolua_fix.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushlightuserdata referenced in function _toluafix_pushusertype_ccobject
1>liblua.lib(tolua_push.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushlightuserdata
1>liblua.lib(tolua_map.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushlightuserdata
1>liblua.lib(tolua_event.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_pushlightuserdata
1>liblua.lib(tolua_map.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_rawget
1>liblua.lib(tolua_event.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_rawget
1>liblua.lib(tolua_fix.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_rawget referenced in function _toluafix_get_function_by_refid
1>liblua.lib(LuaCocos2d.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_rawget
1>liblua.lib(tolua_is.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_rawget
1>liblua.lib(tolua_push.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_rawget
1>liblua.lib(Cocos2dxLuaLoader.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _luaL_checklstring referenced in function _cocos2dx_lua_loader
1>liblua.lib(Cocos2dxLuaLoader.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _luaL_error referenced in function _cocos2dx_lua_loader
1>liblua.lib(tolua_is.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _luaL_error
1>liblua.lib(tolua_map.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _luaL_error
1>liblua.lib(Cocos2dxLuaLoader.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _luaL_loadbuffer referenced in function _cocos2dx_lua_loader
1>liblua.lib(tolua_map.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _luaL_loadbuffer
1>liblua.lib(tolua_is.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_replace referenced in function _push_table_instance
1>liblua.lib(tolua_is.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_isstring referenced in function _lua_isusertable
1>liblua.lib(tolua_is.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_isuserdata referenced in function _lua_isusertype
1>liblua.lib(tolua_map.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_isuserdata
1>liblua.lib(tolua_to.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_isuserdata
1>liblua.lib(tolua_event.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_isuserdata
1>liblua.lib(tolua_is.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_rawequal referenced in function _tolua_fast_isa
1>liblua.lib(tolua_map.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_rawequal
1>liblua.lib(tolua_event.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_rawequal
1>liblua.lib(tolua_is.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_gettable referenced in function _push_table_instance
1>liblua.lib(tolua_to.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_gettable
1>liblua.lib(tolua_event.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_gettable
1>liblua.lib(tolua_is.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_getmetatable referenced in function _lua_isusertype
1>liblua.lib(tolua_push.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_getmetatable
1>liblua.lib(tolua_map.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_getmetatable
1>liblua.lib(tolua_event.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_getmetatable
1>liblua.lib(tolua_is.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_concat referenced in function _lua_isusertable
1>liblua.lib(tolua_push.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_newuserdata referenced in function _tolua_pushusertype
1>liblua.lib(tolua_push.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_settable referenced in function _tolua_pushfieldboolean
1>liblua.lib(tolua_map.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_settable
1>liblua.lib(tolua_event.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_settable
1>liblua.lib(tolua_push.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_setmetatable referenced in function _tolua_pushusertype
1>liblua.lib(tolua_map.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_setmetatable
1>liblua.lib(tolua_event.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_setmetatable
1>liblua.lib(tolua_push.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_setfenv referenced in function _tolua_pushusertype
1>liblua.lib(tolua_map.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_setfenv
1>liblua.lib(tolua_event.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_setfenv
1>liblua.lib(tolua_map.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_getfenv referenced in function _tolua_bnd_getpeer
1>liblua.lib(tolua_event.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _lua_getfenv
1>liblua.lib(tolua_map.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_gc referenced in function _tolua_bnd_releaseownership
1>liblua.lib(tolua_map.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_next referenced in function _mapsuper
1>liblua.lib(tolua_map.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _luaL_newmetatable referenced in function _tolua_newmetatable
1>liblua.lib(tolua_event.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_iscfunction referenced in function _class_index_event
1>liblua.lib(tolua_event.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_tocfunction referenced in function _tolua_ismodulemetatable
1>liblua.lib(tolua_event.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lua_call referenced in function _class_call_event
```

Comment: be sure to include .h files

Comment: @piotruś liblua project is the project I import from the default template. I am not sure whether it is wrong ?

Comment: All those unresolved symbols are functions from the Lua C api runtime. Those errors comes up if the linker cannot find the implementation for said function anywhere. Make sure you're linking against lua5x.dll or lua5x.so since that's normally where they're found.

Comment: @greatwolf thanks . I forgot to add liblua.lib and lua51.lib to my linker..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the **liblua.lib** and **lua51.lib** in the text field.

```
 Project Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies.
```

When you click in the field, you get a `...` key. Click on this key and add one library name per line. Alternatively you can write the names in the field. Separate all entries with space characters.

verify that it's on the command line in

```
 Project Properties -> Linker -> Comamnd Line.
```

Comment: Another error arises after adding liblua.lib and lua51.lib to the additional dependencies. (1)LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'liblua.lib'. When I try manually adding the liblua.lib file to the debug folder, another error pops up (2)error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class cocos2d::LuaEngine * __cdecl cocos2d::LuaEngine::getInstance(void)" (__imp_?getInstance@LuaEngine@cocos2d@@SAPAV12@XZ) and error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class cocos2d::LuaStack * __thiscall cocos2d::LuaEngine::getLuaStack

Comment: What vexes me is that the lua tests compile but trying to add lua to my cocos2dx projects is like pulling my nails out

Answer (score 0):

I finally get it, in case anyone encounters a similar problem. To get lua to work with cocos2d-x, you need the following

1. add libluacocos2d project to your solution. (its found in `[cocos2dx-root-folder]/cocos/scripting/lua-bindings/proj.win32/libluacocos2d.vcxproj`)
2. Go to your `project properties>Common Properties>References>click add New Reference` and add the libluacocos2d
3. Go to your `project properties>Configuration Properties>C/C++>General>Additional Include Directories` and add these folders `$(EngineRoot)cocos\scripting\lua-bindings\auto` , `$(EngineRoot)cocos\scripting\lua-bindings\manual` , `$(EngineRoot)external\lua\lua` , `$(EngineRoot)external\lua\tolua`

   4. Go to your `project properties>Configuration Properties>C/C++>Preprocessor>Preprocessor Definitions` and add `_USRLUASTATIC` or else you get errors like `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "_declspec(dllimport) public: static class cocos2d::LuaEngine * __cdecl cocos2d::LuaEngine::getInstance(void)" (__imp?getInstance@LuaEngine@cocos2d@@SAPAV12@XZ)`
   5. Go to your `project properties>Configuration Properties>Linker>input>additional Dependencies` and add `lua51.lib`

By now every thing should compile and work.My cocos2d setup is cocos2d-x 3.10, Android NDK r9b ,visual studio 2013, python 2.7, android sdk 19

Ps: I got the answer on a Chinese forum http://m.blog.csdn.net/j0903/article/details/73289291